# Copy file into newly created directories and rename issue

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a batch file that works with a folder full of images. (1) For each image it creates a folder and renames the folder with the name of the images (2) it then puts the images inside the folders (3) then duplicates the images and renames the copy with "- origional". All that works great, but then at step (4) I'm trying to then put a file from a different directory into all the folders that were just created, and rename it the same as the folders.

```
(1) for %%i in (*.jpg) do mkdir "%%~ni"
(2) for %%i in (*.jpg) do move "%%i" "%%~ni"
(3) for /R %%f in (*.jpg) do copy "%%~f" "%%~dpnf - Original%%~xf"
(4) copy "C:\Projects\test.csv" "%%~ni\%%~dpnf.csv"
```

I nearly got it working with this:

```
copy "C:\Projects\test.csv" "%~dp0\hello.csv"
```

Which brought it to the directory of the batch file and renamed it. But I'm having trouble copying it into the new directories and renaming it.

New edited code:

```
for %%i in (*.jpg) do mkdir "%%~ni"
for %%i in (*.jpg) do move "%%i" "%%~ni"
for /R %%f in (*.jpg) do copy "%%~f" "%%~dpnf - Original%%~xf"
for /D %%a  in ("%~dp0\*.*") do xcopy  /y  /d  C:\Projects\test.csv "%%a\"
```

Here's the final code that works for anyone else looking for this:

```
for %%i in (*.jpg) do mkdir "%%~ni"
for %%i in (*.jpg) do move "%%i" "%%~ni"
for /R %%f in (*.jpg) do copy "%%~f" "%%~dpnf - Original%%~xf"
for /D %%a in ("*") do copy /y /d C:\Projects\test.csv "%%a\%%a.csv"
```

Comment: Your last line of code needs to be nested inside the `FOR` command in order for it to be able to access the FOR variable.

Comment: Okay, so I think I've done that, but it's still not understanding the variables? I've put the edited code in my main question. Pretty sure this is causing the issue `"%%~ni\%%~dpnf.csv"` But I've tried eveything I can think of in there.

Comment: You are trying to use the variables from two different `FOR` commands that are not nested.  What I mean by nested is a parenthesized code block.  You are way over complicating this and making your code very inefficient.

Comment: Yeah I'm not really sure how to do that, but I'll look into it after it works. I've managed to get it to copy all the files into the new folders. But it's still not renaming unfortunatley.

`for /D %%a  in ("%~dp0\*.*") do xcopy  /y  /d  C:\Projects\test.csv "%%a\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line is too complex. If you just want to match the directories into the current path, this should be enough:

```
for /D %%a in ("*") do xcopy /y /d C:\Projects\test.csv "%%a"
```

## Edit

To rename the CSV files as the folder they are copied into, do it like this:

```
for /D %%a in ("*") do xcopy /y /d C:\Projects\test.csv "%%a\%%a.csv"
```

Comment: Okay great, thanks. Is there a way to rename the csv files the same name as the folders they're going into? That's the other half of what I'm trying to do. I've been trying stuff like this: `for /D %%a in ("*\test2.csv") do xcopy /y /d C:\Projects\test.csv "%%a"` But I need to make the csv names the same as the directories done in the first line of my code.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot, worked prefectly. I did change it from `xcopy` to `copy` to stop it asking the "Does xxx specify a file name…" message, but it works fine now.